# PHP Extract Single String from List of Values

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I need some assistance with php. I have been trying several things for the past several days including str_replace to no avail.

I have a field that may contain from 1 to 20 values, all listed on their own line, there is no html code in that field to separate them and some of the values may have their own spaces in between, so separating by space doesnt work.

What I need is to extract every single string of each line and convert it to code.

```
    <p>For example, my field with values looks like this: </p>
<p><b>lang_fld </b><br>
    ------
    <br>
    English<br>
    Spanish<br>
    German<br>
        French</p>
```

What I have in mind is to extract each line, ex. "English" from that string, and create a line of code like

```
<img src="images/flags/english.png> English
```

Basically I want to add the flag graphic to the word

I already tried

```
echo str_replace('English','&lt;img src="images/flags/english.png&gt;,lang_fld)<br>
...and so on
```

what I get after going through every single possible value is a bunch error 
messages (different every time since I keep making changes - by guessing)

Can someone offer an easier option to do this? Not all 20 values will be in 
that areatext field, some may contain just one language, some ten, some all 20, 
etc.

Thank you!

Comment: tried this? $languages =explode("\n", $languages);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have all the values on a separate line, you can do `explode()` on the string to convert it to array of separate items, then loop through the array with `foreach` and perform any modifications with the single item. After you are done with the items and you would like to get them back together, you can use `implode()` to combine them into a single string.

A short sample ( you can of course use a `for` loop, I just prefer `foreach` here as it shows you better what is happening with the data ):

```
$text =
"French language
Italian language
English language";

$items = explode( "\n", $text ); // Split by newline ( you can also use "<br>" as separator )

$result = array(); // Modified data will be placed here

foreach ( $items as $item )
{
    // Do something with $item
    $item = "<img src=\"images/flags/$item.png\"> $item";
    $result[] = $item;
}

// Merge them back together
$text = implode("\n", $result);
```

Comment: Shadow Walker, thank you. Your suggestion worked. I made a couple of modifications but with your code it was very easy. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks HemChe for your input as well.